# How to replace text on an element nested with elements in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I've scoured the net and SO for this particular question and its' related topics thereof. Some solutions come close but is inapplicable as offered solutions is limited to look for absolute points/index inside the element (e.g. first and last nodes).

I'm looking for a way in jquery/javascript to replace a text on the same level with other elements found anywhere in an element.

```
<div id="master_element">
  <a href="#" id="link">Erp. a text</a>

  **This must be the only text replaced**

  <em>Herp. em text</em>
  <div id="nest_meh">
    <div id="we_need_to_dig_deeper">
      nested div from hell
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by *"text on the same level with other elements found anywhere in an element."*?

Comment: Oh I got it, maybe: any text inside master_element that is not inside another tag?

Comment: @Liam, i think that he mean on text which is not inside any other element, except main div? All other texts are wrapped in some tags... but, waiting for clarification... :)

Comment: @Liam, FrancescoMM and nevermind is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really don't get why this would be an issue, you target the elements based on markup, how else would you target them :

```
document.getElementById('link').nextSibling.nodeValue = 'something else';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5JdX/)

**EDIT:**

to replace textnodes that are not wrapped in elements etc, no matter where they occur inside the master element, you'd do something like :

```
var elems = document.getElementById('master_element').childNodes;

for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    var el = elems[i];
    if (el.nodeType === 3 && el.nodeValue.trim().length) 
        el.nodeValue = 'something else';
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5JdX/1/)

Comment: I think he means any text node inside master_element that is not inside another tag, maybe after <a> maybe before.. maybe..

Comment: @adeneo thanks!! the first solution was the 

"limited to look for absolute points/index inside the element (e.g. first and last nodes)"

i was talking about. But the second solution was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

a jQuery bases solution, it replaces all the text nodes - you will have to tweak it

```
$('#master_element').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = 'new'; //need to make it cross browser 
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m92VS/)